# I upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 23.10 and now I'm stuck in tty1

Tags: login, 23.10

After upgrading Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10, when started, shows in the top left corner:

"Ubuntu 23.10 [My name] tty1
[My name] login: "

I try put my username and Password but always appears "Login incorrect"

Comment: Easiest solution is to fresh install Ubuntu 23.10. You can use the live USB to back up (any) existing data in your home folder.

Comment: So I need to uninstall and reinstall this version?

Comment: You cannot uninstall an OS. Just reinstall on top. The installer can format the root partition for you.